# how to i turn this query to a sub query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

how can I change this query where I want to turn the max to a subquery where when I enter the sql the only thing that will appear is the id and first name.

```
SELECT staff.staff_id,staff.firstname,max(payment.amount)
from payment ,staff
where payment.staff_id=staff.staff_id
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0):

use explicit join

```
SELECT staff.staff_id,staff.firstname,max(payment.amount)
from payment join staff
on  payment.staff_id=staff.staff_id
```

but i think you want

```
   SELECT staff.staff_id,staff.firstname,p.amount
    from payment p join staff
    on  p.staff_id=staff.staff_id
    where p.amount= select max(amount) from payment
```

Comment: SELECT staff.staff_id, staff.first_name,staff.last_name
from payment p ,staff s
where p.staff_id=s.staff_id and p.amount=(SELECT max(amount)from payment                                                       i want something like this without explicit join , but htis doesnt work

Comment: @alinas share sample data and its output

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
SELECT staff.staff_id,staff.firstname
from payment inner join staff
on payment.staff_id=staff.staff_id where payment.amount in (select max(payment.amount) from payment)
```

Comment: SELECT staff.staff_id, staff.first_name,staff.last_name from payment p ,staff s where p.staff_id=s.staff_id and p.amount=(SELECT max(amount)from payment i want something like this without explicit join , but htis doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

From `JOIN` to (correlated) sub-query:

```
SELECT staff.staff_id, staff.firstname,
       (SELECT MAX(payment.amount) 
        FROM payment
        WHERE payment.staff_id = staff.staff_id)
FROM staff
```